# Dropdown list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to implement a simple Jquery drop down.

**HTML**

```
<h2> Networked Graphs</h2>
<p> Select the node ID from the drop down to see graphs up to a depth of 5 </p>
<form id="my form">
  <label for="Node_type">Node_Type</label>
  <select id="dropdown_change">
    <option value="Customer">Customer</option>
    <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
    <option value="ID_Card">ID_Card</option>
  </select>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

**This is the jquery code:**

```
var selectID = $("#dropdown_change").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/echo/html/',
  data: {
    html: "<span>This is the ajax response...</span>",
    delay: 2
   },

   success: function(data) {
     showMsg('SUCCESS: ' + data);
   },

   error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     document.getElementById('dropdown_change').selectedIndex = 0;
     showMsg('ERROR: ' + errorThrown);
     return false;
   }
});

})  // closes ?
```

Selecting from the drop down and clicking on the submit button should display the success message 'SUCCESS: This is the Ajax response'.

Even though I specify "type: POST" and **SUCCESS** as well as **ERROR** messages, it fails with the below error:

> {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishy1988/dsspureq/1/). Trying to learn javascript/jquery.

Comment: Check the web servers logs and make sure the request is coming in as a POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery Ajax is running as soon as the page loads. It does not run when the button is clicked. When the button is clicked, the HTML form is being submitted.

The way to do this would be to add a listener to the button that intercepts the submit and calls the jQuery Ajax. It would look something like this:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
  var selectID = $("#dropdown_change").val();
  $.ajax({...
  return false;
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nf2d8juh/)

Answer (score 0):

After jquery 1.9.0, you should use

```
method: "POST"
```

instead of

```
type: "POST"
```

[Link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)